# Animation in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I would like to ask to you to share some ideas about how do you implement an animation support in your OpenGL application. 
For example, if we would like in case of the some event fired from the user input, animate a Ball particle on the screen, how do we need organize our code? :

1. Set Animation property like a member of Ball particle object ? (That contains a set of matricies to apply to the owner model, delay of between them, is playback animation or not and so on..)
2. Need to have some central repository that contains a relation between a Ball particle and applied animation to it (I, honestly, would prefer this one). ?
3. Somethihg else ...?

And after what about a rendering ? How to do it fluid and fast ? (I know this is very context sensitive, but just to give an idea..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would define an *Animation* class, which can implement the following animations:

- Rotation/translation/scale animation
- Key frame animation
- Skinning animation

Of course, one of the animation techniques listed above need some generic access to the *Object* class.

*RotoTranslation* animation requires access to the *Object* model view matrix; *KeyFrame* animation requires access to the model vertices buffers; *Skinning* animation requires access to the rendering state of the *Object* (shader attributes and programs, or vertex attributes using extensions).

Apart skinning, the interpolation of generic values (floats, vector or matrices) shall be implemented, in order to change the values using an interpolation formula (nice those linked by genpfault). So an *Interpolator* class shall be able to ease the introduction of new interpolation equations.

An Animation class uses a set of *Interpolator* instances to execute the animation (changing the values to be interpolated). How the values are choosed, accessed and modified (ranges) shall be defined at *Object* class.

At this point there must be a *TimeLine* class which defines the time elapsed (which could not be the real one), which trigger *Animation* instances (or perhaps the single *Interpolator* instances) making the interpolated values advance the intermediate value.

The *Animation* instances are queued on the *TimeLine* class, so it knows which *Animation* instances are active. The activation could be caused by user input or programmatically using internally generated events. To terminate the *Animation* execution, the *Animation* class could define a *IsTerminated* method is order to be dequeued from the *TimeLine* instance (perhaps the *Animation* could loop back the animation to have a continuous animation).

---

Of course everything depending on your real needs.

In the case the computation of the animation could take long time, you could cache the entire model data and run the animation in a separated thread. Once terminated, the model could be updated blocking the rendering loop.

However, I would consider to inline the animation processing by issuing proper data to shader programs allowing a faster computation, which could enhances system performances.

Comment: Wow, thank you for detailed explanation of your ideas.

Answer (score 4):

As far as "fluid and fast" goes, you may want to look into various [easing equations](http://www.gizma.com/easing/) to apply to your animation interpolation value.

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL doesn't offer support for animation; you will need to write your own framework (for example using GLX, [see this article](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Programming_OpenGL_in_Linux:_Programming_Animations_with_GLX_and_Xlib)) or use an existing framework like the [ones mentioned here](http://www.thefreecountry.com/sourcecode/graphics.shtml).

Comment: I know, and my question actually was, how to organize a code to implement it. Thanks for lnks.