# suspend a function for sometime in opengl

Tags: opengl

I have a function Drwa() this is rendering a triangle on screen.and also i have another Draw_poly() which is rendering a Rectangle on screen. And i also i m rotating rectangle and triangle both simultaneously.I want to keep speed of rotation different for both how will i do ?

Let suppose i am moving an object on screen and another i m rotating then how will i do ? That's why i m looking for function moving of object will keep time limited and rotating object will not keep time.So rotation will be fast and moving of object will be slow

Comment: _When i m using sleep function this is suspending whole function.I want to wait for 1 second only that particular function._ What do you mean exactly?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Rotate one less/slower than the other:

```
static float rot_a = 0.0;
static float rot_b = 0.0;

rot_a += 1.0;
rot_b += 0.5;

glPushMatrix();
glRotatef( rot_a, 0, 0, 1 );
Draw_A();
glPopMatrix();

glPushMatrix();
glRotatef( rot_b, 0, 0, 1 );
Draw_B();
glPopMatrix();
```

Alternatively you can spin up some threads that modify your object positions and `sleep()` without blocking the render thread.

```
Position obj_a;
Position obj_b;

void thread_1()
{
    while( !done )
    {
        sleep(1);
        modify_pos( obj_a );
    }
}


void thread_2()
{
    while( !done )
    {
        sleep(2);
        modify_pos( obj_b );
    }
}


void draw()
{
    glPushMatrix();
    position_object( obj_a );
    Draw_A();
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    position_object( obj_b );
    Draw_B();
    glPopMatrix();
}


int main()
{
...
launch_thread( thread_1 );
launch_thread( thread_2 );

...
return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's good can i not give any predefined function for timer for not execution for limited time.Let suppose i am moving an object on screen and another i m rotating then how will i do ? That's why i m looking for function moving of object will keep time limited and rotating object will not keep time.So rotaion will be fast and moving of object will be slow.

Comment: spinning threads to update the transformations ?! that is overkill !

Comment: @rotoglup: Oh, no argument here.

Answer (score 2):

First, define your rotation as angle per second. Then in your main draw function, compute the elapsed time in second, multiply by the angular speed, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to partecipate with a an answer of mine.

The answer of *genpfault* could be good as much as you need, but if you would like to produce a good animation you need to design a better software.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290997/animation-in-opengl/3304261#3304261), look at my answer. However, reading another your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535937/how-to-move-triangle-on-plane-in-opengl), I think you are missing some fundamental point: learn OpenGL architecture, practice on each OpenGL entry point, read books.

At last, but not least, I would you suggest to search for answer already told on *stackoverflow*. This is supposed to be a *question & answer* site...